# Can the IComparer class in C++/CLI have a template argument list?

Tags: c++-cli

Using Visual Studio 2015 with this simple code I'm getting the message: "class System::Collections::IComparer may not have a template argument list" when trying to define the MarketOrder_SortMaxPriceToMinPrice class.

In C# I can create the class/method with template arguments but in C++ I can only do it with generic Object^ handles.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections;

ref class MarketOrder : public IComparable<MarketOrder^> //Works fine
{
    public:
    virtual int CompareTo(MarketOrder^ other);
};

ref class MarketOrder_SortMaxPriceToMinPrice : IComparer<MarketOrder^> //Not allowed
{
    public:
    virtual int Compare(MarketOrder^ x, MarketOrder^ y);
};
```

Is this a C++/CLI limitation or am I doing something wrong?

The following code works for me:

```
ref class MarketOrder_SortMaxPriceToMinPrice : IComparer
{
    public:
    virtual int Compare(Object^ x, Object^ y);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `IComparer` classes, one [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) and one [non-generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). You need to reference the one in namespace `System::Collections::Generic`.

Also, the recommendation is to subclass [`Comparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx?cs-lang=cpp), rather than directly implementing the interface. This way, you automatically get the non-generic overload.